# Question about new placement related to class constructor

Tags: c++

As far as I know the new keyword performs the process of allocating memory and call constructor of object.

```
class X{
public:
    int x;
    X(int a):x(a){std::cout<<"X(int a)"<<std::endl;}
    ~X(){std::cout<<"Delete X"<<std::endl;}
};
int main()
{
    X* ptr = new X{2};
    // allocate mem sizeof(X);
    // call constructor of X{2};
    delete(ptr);
}
```

Also new operator can be modified like below code.

```
X* ptr = static_cast<X*>( operator new(sizeof(X)) );
new(ptr) X{2};
```

My question is how to allocate constructor to ptr?
The "new(ptr) X{2}" is implemented like this.
[image]
It looks like there is no code that associated with class constructors.
How does this call a constructor?

Comment: You may consider the _placement new_ mechanism as an explicit constructor call (in case of a class type). Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/1136ha6P6.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`new` expressions and `operator new` are not the same thing. Unfortunately, they have names that suggest that `operator new` is like e.g. an operator overload `operator+` for the `+` operator, which is however not the case.

A `new` expression may call an `operator new` overload, but that is only for the allocation step you are talking about, which is why the standard library placement-new `operator new` implementation is just a noop.

The construction of the object, including the constructor call if any is to be done, is an intrinsic part of the semantics of the `new` expression itself that can't be modified. There is no function implementing it and there wouldn't (generally) be any way to implement the construction of an object other than using a `new` expression itself.

---

Also, note that your replacement for the allocating `new` expression is not correct with your example `X`. `X` has a non-trivial destructor and is therefore not an *implicit-lifetime type*. This means that an `X` object is created only by the placement-new expression in the second line. The result of the `operator new` call (and also the result of the `static_cast`) will not be pointing to any `X` object.

It should be

```
void* mem = operator new(sizeof(X));
X* ptr = new(mem) X{2};
```

instead, so that `ptr` is guaranteed to point to the newly created object.

In general, you also need to make sure that the pointer returned from `operator new` is suitably aligned for the type `X`. Otherwise, the placement-new expression will not work correctly.

Since C++17 there is the `__STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__` macro against which you can test alignment to verify that the standard library's global replaceable `operator new` implementations without `std::align_val_t` parameter will guarantee suitable alignment:

```
static_assert(alignof(X) <= __STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__);
```

If that is not satisfied you must use the `std::align_val_t` overload:

```
void* mem = operator new(sizeof(X), std::align_val_t{alignof(X)});
```

Also, note that you should then (and only then) call the corresponding `operator delete` with the alignment to deallocate the memory (otherwise without the alignment argument):

```
ptr->~X();
operator delete(mem, std::align_val_t{alignof(X)});
```

The allocating `new X{2}` and `delete(ptr);` expressions do all of this decision-making on which `operator new` and `operator delete` to use internally, based on knowing the type of the operand.

(The above alignment consideration applies to the global replaceable `operator new`/`operator delete` overloads. A user-replacement of these `operator new` overloads must also satisfy the same requirements. However, a custom *overload* (rather than a replacement) may have other behavior and might be called from these expressions as a result of overload resolution.)

Comment: Thanks @user17732522, It is really useful information for me.
Thank you!